# How common are single quotes (apostrophes) in Windows usernames? What about in Ireland?

Tags: windows, bash

today we discovered our developer-focused GUI app doesn't work on systems where the username contains an apostrophe. Because although it's multi-platform, part of it runs in a linux VM where shell scripts are generated on the fly. We did the quoting needed to handle names and paths containing spaces, but didn't figure on single quotes.

It looks like `scoop` doesn't work in such environments either, but I need to do more investigation there. If that's the case, I can't imagine many developers insisting that their Windows name be their actual name.

Looking for feedback to figure out how I should prioritize this bug, which should be fixable, just not in a few hours.

Comment: The question is what ? Does adding UTF support to your application is a good idea ? Imagine thing like; éèçàô etc...

Answer (score 1):

> How common are single quotes (apostrophes) in Windows usernames?

That is a bit irrelevant. (Nor is it something that can be answered.)

You found that it is not only an allowed character in a Windows user name, but that people actually do assign usernames with that character.

So, if you can, please fix your broken code.

And then take into account that from AD and for modern Windows versions/applications/libraries there are surprisingly few restrictions with regards to for example the `sAMAccountName` attribute:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11216.active-directory-requirements-for-creating-objects.aspx#Objects_with_sAMAccountName_Attribute

As a counter point:
Regardless of what is technically allowed and possible in Windows/AD usually  organisations have implemented a much stricter naming policy for accounts.  Such policies restrict usernames to provide as much (backward) compatibility as possible, because in heterogenous environments yours is not the only application that breaks on usernames that don't meet "old" conventions.
In practice that means one indeed sees mostly relatively short [POSIX compliant usernames](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_437) with only characters from the [portable character set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282)  `a-Z` , `0-9` and sometimes a hyphen `-`, underscore `_` or dot  `.` somewhere in the middle. In turn such a naming convention provides little incentive to fix/modernise those applications.